# Unable to iterate fields in domain filter

Tags: odoo

I have 2 classes "class" and "student" where the relation between them is one2many. i.e one class will have many students

Then the third class to map where i need to make an entry by selecting one class and selecting one student. So i would like to filter students only that of the class selected.

I implemented the below domain filter

```
<field name="class"/> # many2one field
<field name="student" domain="[('student.cols.id','=',class)]"/>  # many2one field where cols is the many2one field to class "class". In the right side i am able to get the id correct
```

It fails with the below error message

```
raise ValueError("Invalid field %r in leaf %r" % (left, str(leaf)))
```

Kindly clarify. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in `domain`, dont use `student.cols.id`. If `cols` is the many2one field in `student` then use `domain="[('cols','=',class)]"`.
For example if `student_id` is a field in which the model has a many2one relation to `class_id`, then use

```
<field name="student_id" domain="[('class_id','=',class)]"/>
```